# WCF Service to read, write, edit, delete data from SQL database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to build a web service in .NET, which will interact with an SQL database. This web service will later on be consumed by an MVC where this data will be displayed and interacted with.

I have the database ready, the connection between the database and the web service has been made and I have added my MVC item into my solution. I have my Create, Read And Update function working, but the Delete refuses to work.

When the Delete link is clicked, it displays my record, asking me to confirm deletion and when I click Yes, it doesn't work/delete. Please help.

This is my Service.cs file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;

// NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Service" in code, svc and config file together.
public class Service : IService
{
    public List<Student> GetStudent()
    {
        var objContext = new ContosoUniversityDataEntities();
        var students = objContext.Students;

        return students.ToList<Student>();
    }

    public string InsertStudent(string firstName, string lastName, string middleName)
    {
        try
        {
            var objContext = new ContosoUniversityDataEntities();

            Student s = new Student()
            {
                FirstName = firstName,
                LastName = lastName,
                MiddleName = middleName,
                EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Now
            };

            objContext.Students.Add(s);
            objContext.SaveChanges();

            return "Success";
        }
        catch { return "failure"; }
    }
    public string Update(int id, string firstName, string middleName, string lastName)
    {
        try
        {
            var objContext = new ContosoUniversityDataEntities();
            var s = (from d in objContext.Students where d.StudentID == id select d).Single();
            s.FirstName = firstName;
            s.MiddleName = middleName;
            s.LastName = lastName;

            objContext.SaveChanges();
            return "Success";
        }
        catch { return "failure"; }

    }
    public string Delete(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            var objContext = new ContosoUniversityDataEntities();
            var s = (from d in objContext.Students where d.StudentID == id select d);

            foreach(var y in s)
            {
                objContext.Students.Remove(y);
            }

            objContext.SaveChanges();
            return "Success";
        }
        catch { return "failure"; }
    }




    public List<Student> InsertStudent()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }


    public string Update(string firstName, string lastName, string middleName)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

This is my DeleteController class

```
using MvcWcfApplication.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MvcWcfApplication.Controllers
{
    public class DeleteController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Delete/

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            ServiceReference1.ServiceClient obj = new ServiceReference1.ServiceClient();

            var students = obj.GetStudent();
            var std = students.Where(s => s.StudentID == id).FirstOrDefault();
            return View(std);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Delete(Studentdata mb)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid) //checking model is valid or not
            {
                ServiceReference1.ServiceClient obj = new ServiceReference1.ServiceClient();

                string message = obj.Delete(mb.StudentID);
                if (message == "Success")
                {
                    ViewData["result"] = message;
                    ModelState.Clear(); //clearing model
                    return View();
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "We are currently down");
                    return View();
                }


            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Error in saving data");
                return View();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

This is Delete.cshtml

```
@model MvcWcfApplication.ServiceReference1.Student

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Delete";
}

@{
    if (ViewData["result"] != "" && ViewData["result"] != null)
    {
        ViewData["result"] = null;
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            alert("Data deleted Successfully");
        </script>
    }
}

<h2>Delete</h2>

<h3>Are you sure you want to delete this?</h3>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Student</legend>

    <div class="display-label">
         @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EnrollmentDate)
    </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.EnrollmentDate)
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">
         @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)
    </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstName)
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">
         @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)
    </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LastName)
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">
         @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MiddleName)
    </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.MiddleName)
    </div>
</fieldset>
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {

    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <p>
        <input id="Submit" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want delete');" type="submit"
               value="Delete" /> |
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index", "Db")
    </p>
}
```

This is UpdateController class

```
using MvcWcfApplication.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MvcWcfApplication.Controllers
{
    public class UpdateController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Update/

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Update(int id)
        {
            ServiceReference1.ServiceClient obj = new ServiceReference1.ServiceClient();

            var students = obj.GetStudent();
            var std = students.Where(s => s.StudentID == id).FirstOrDefault();
            return View(std);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Update(Studentdata MB)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid) //checking model is valid or not
            {
                ServiceReference1.ServiceClient obj = new ServiceReference1.ServiceClient();

                string message = obj.Update(MB.StudentID, MB.FirstName, MB.LastName, MB.MiddleName);
                if (message == "Success")
                {
                    ViewData["result"] = message;
                    ModelState.Clear(); //clearing model
                    return View();
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "We are currently down");
                    return View();
                }


            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Error in saving data");
                return View();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

This is my Update.cshtml

```
@model MvcWcfApplication.ServiceReference1.Student

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Update";
}

@{
    if (ViewData["resultUpdate"] != "" && ViewData["resultUpdate"] != null)
    {
        ViewData["resultUpdate"] = null;
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            alert("Data updated Successfully");
        </script>
    }
}

<h2>Update</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Student</legend>



        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MiddleName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MiddleName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MiddleName)
        </div>

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.StudentID)

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: Well start by casting the exception in the `Delete` method to a variable: `catch(Exception ex) {}` and find out what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are submitting empty form without values put Id as a  hidden field

```
 @model MvcWcfApplication.ServiceReference1.Student

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Delete";
}

@{
    if (ViewData["result"] != "" && ViewData["result"] != null)
    {
        ViewData["result"] = null;
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            alert("Data deleted Successfully");
        </script>
    }
}

<h2>Delete</h2>

<h3>Are you sure you want to delete this?</h3>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Student</legend>

    <div class="display-label">
         @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EnrollmentDate)
    </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.EnrollmentDate)
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">
         @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)
    </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstName)
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">
         @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)
    </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LastName)
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">
         @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MiddleName)
    </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.MiddleName)
    </div>
</fieldset>
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {

    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.StudentID)
    <p>
        <input id="Submit" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want delete');" type="submit"
               value="Delete" /> |
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index", "Db")
    </p>
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this and it doesn't work.

Comment: Then the reason would be your Model.IsValid, because everything except the studentID in your model are either null or default values. If you have any required attributes Model will become invalid. check whether it enters the if also see if you see StudentID on the controller end.

Comment: It worked! Thank you. Why does the Required Attribute hinder the record from being deleted?

Comment: because you have a if(Model.IsValid) and your form has only one property StudentID if you want full form to post back put hidden fields for remaining properties.